# ExtJs 3.4 set progressbar dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I'm using plupload to upload some files, my boss asked me to update some things like having a progressbar instead off some text, before I started the uploader was something like this:

```
App.uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    // code omitted

    url: "actions/Upload.aspx",

    init: {
        //ownerwindow
        Error: function (up, err) {
            // code omitted
        },

        PostInit: function () {
            // code omitted
        },

        UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
            var p = up.ownerwindow;
            var totalpercent = ((Math.round(up.total.loaded / up.total.size * 100)))
            p.getEl().mask('Uploading: <br/>Total: ' + totalpercent + '%<br/>File: ' + file.percent + '%');
        },

        FileUploaded: function (up, file, response) {
            // code omitted
        },

        UploadComplete: function (up, response) {
            // code omitted
        },

        FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
            // code omitted
        }
    }
});

App.uploader.init();
```

but now I want 2 progressbars to provide the feedback

1. showing file %
2. showing remaining files to upload

So I tried initializing the progressbars inside the `UploadProgress` but that didn't work

then I tried setting it just above the `App.uploader`:

```
var upgradeProgressBar = new Ext.ProgressBar({
    id: 'pbar1'
});
```

and setting the values in the `UploadProgress`:

```
p.getEl().mask('<div id="upload"><div id="fileProgress"></div><div id="totalProgress"></div></div>');

upgradeProgressBar.width = 50 / totalpercent;
upgradeProgressBar.text = up.total.uploaded + ' / ' + up.files.length + ' ( ' + up.total.failed + ' failed )';
upgradeProgressBar.renderTo = 'totalProgress';
```

but no luck there either, then I get something like this:

[image: Progressbar?]

**EDIT:**
So as @mindparse mentioned, I could make a window and there add a panel that has the progressbars. But I am still new to the extJS thing so I have the following:

```
        win = new Ext.Window({
            applyTo: 'viewport',
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            plain: true,

            items: new Ext.Panel({
                title: 'Upload Progress',
                preventBodyReset: true,
                width: 400,
                html: '<div id="upload"><div id="fileProgress"></div><div id="totalProgress"></div></div>'
            })
        });

        var upgradeProgressBar1 = new Ext.ProgressBar({
            id: 'pbar1',
            renderTo: 'fileProgress'
        });
        var upgradeProgressBar2 = new Ext.ProgressBar({
            id: 'pbar2',
            renderTo: 'totalProgress'
        });
```

this throws an  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null`

this is the viewport:

```
App.Viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    id: 'viewport',
    border: true,
    items: [new App.regions.north.Panel(), { xtype: 'regionswestpanel', margins: '0 0 5 5' }, { xtype: 'regionscenterpanel', margins: '0 5 5 0' }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (viewport) {
        }
    }
});
```

and Would it be better to make the porgressbars public, or can I access them in my upload thingy?

Comment: Can you post your config for the progress bar. It looks like its being shown on a panel in a modal window too?

Comment: config? all the code on the progressbar is in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [updateProgress](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar-method-updateProgress) and [updateText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar-method-updateText) methods to dynamically change the appearance.

Also, you should specify renderTo as a config option in your progressBar:

```
var upgradeProgressBar = new Ext.ProgressBar({
    id: 'pbar1',
    renderTo: 'totalProgress'
});
```

**EDIT**:

As per my suggestion in the comments, just use an Ext.Window, something like this:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
                layout: 'auto',
                title: 'Upload Progress',
                width: 500, 
                closeAction: 'hide',
                modal: true,
                padding: 5,
                items: [
                    {xtype:'progress', id: 'pbar1'},
                    {xtype:'progress', id: 'pbar2'}
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Thanks,but if I set the renderTo when I define my progressbar (outside the pluploader stuff) I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null`

Comment: Ah that will be because ExtJS is trying to render that progress bar to totalProgress div, before the div has actually been rendered. As a test you could move the code to create the upgradeProgressBar into UploadProgress after mask has been called. See if that works for you, I'm not so sure you should be creating div's like you are in the mask call.

Comment: well the idea of creating the divs, was because I would love to have multiple progressbars on the mask (one for a signle file, and one for total progress) so moving it to the UploadProgress would create 2 progressbars every iteration (I can clean them at the end of the function, but still I'll have to create them)

Comment: How about using a modal Ext.Window which contains a panel with two progress bars, then just show\hide the window as required and update the progress bars when needed? That would achieve the same thing, but would allow you to work with pure ExtJS components rather than hand crafted dom.

Comment: updated the question, with some new code (I don't know a lot on extJS, just enough so I can modify code, but adding some more, is gonna requires some help)

Comment: Take a look at my edit in my original answer, no need for renderTo\applyTo like you have tried. Also, you can use xtypes (lazy init) for quick creation of child items.

Comment: Works like a charm! Any chance on making it have text in front ? or around?